# How to combine three XREF tables into one?

Tags: php, mysql

I have three XREF tables.

1. `order_delivery_xref` : order_id (int), delivery_id (int)
2. `delivery_invoice_xref` : delivery_id (int), invoice_id (int)
3. `invoice_order_xref` : invoice_id (int), order_id (int)

I now need to combine them into a common table, like so:

`order_delivery_invoice_xref` : order_id (int), delivery_id (int), invoice_id (int)

Is there a way to do this using a query? or a procedure? or using a php script + mysql queries?

Notes:

1. An `delivery_id` always exists with an `order_id`
2. An `invoice_id` doesn't always exist, and needs to be `null` in the row, if missing

---

Here's what i have tried:

```
SELECT order_id, delivery_id
FROM order_delivery_xref
WHERE 1
```

... and so on for all the three tables.

Then I run a `foreach()` loop in `php` for the first array, check using `isset()` function for other arrays (replace `NULL` where `!isset()`), and create a table>tr>td in html.

I'm not quite sure if this is the correct method. Can someone suggest a better method?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do. To do it once, this will work:

> create table odx (order_id int, delivery_id int); create table dix
>   (delivery_id int, invoice_id int); create table iox (invoice_id int,
>   order_id int);
>
> insert into odx values (1, 11), (2, 22), (3,33); insert into dix
>   values (22, 333), (22, 444), (33, 555); insert into iox values (333,
>   1), (444, 2), (555, 2);
>
> create table odix (order_id int, delivery_id int, invoice_id int);
>
> insert into odix (order_id, delivery_id, invoice_id)  select
>   odx.order_id, odx.delivery_id, dix.invoice_id from odx
>       left join dix on dix.delivery_id = odx.delivery_id
>       left join iox on iox.order_id = odx.order_id;

But you have to make your own decisions about how to join the tables - because of the contents of the three tables, you can join them many ways with different results.

Also, you have to figure out what to do when any of the subsidiary tables changes - do you recreate the odix table from scratch or just add new or changed records.

You'll find that doing as much of this as possible in MySQL will be faster than in PHP - MySQL is very good at joining tables together and aggregating data in this way.

Finally, you probably want to think about why you are doing this - why put the data in another table. With MySQL, you can always assemble the data together to view them this way, so copying the data doesn't seem to make sense. It creates redundancy in your database, which can get confusing and difficult to manage.

Check out a few references on "normalization" to get some ideas.

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified. I don't want to keep the three tables once this is done. I will just `drop` it.

Comment: Okay, but perhaps you don't need to build the new table - since you can get everything you need from it from a version of a query - depending on what you're doing with it. But, if you want the table, I've shown you how to build it - does that work for you?